# Is it safe to initialize Firebase on background thread in Android? What to watch out for?

Tags: android, multithreading, firebase

In my setup, Firebase takes ~250ms to init (measured on Nexus 5 as a difference in "time to first display" with and without `FirebaseInitProvider / CrashlyticsInitProvider` on cold start). This is a problem because without Firebase my app takes just 350ms to cold start, and Firebase makes that double.

I'm considering disabling the default `FirebaseInitProvider` and `CrashlyticsInitProvider`, which run on the main thread before application starts, and do the initialization manually on a background thread (e.g. starting it from `Application.onCreate()`).

Q: is it safe to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` on a background thread? And if so, what should I watch out for? I am aware that if need to e.g. `getUser()` while Firebase is still starting in background, I have to implement some locking so that my thread waits for it to be ready. I also don't care about accurate screen time reporting, so it's not a problem if Firebase Analyics registers its activity lifecycle callback with a delay.

P.S. There's a `synchronized` block within `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()`, which means the engineers assumed someone would try to call that from another thread. I'm more worried about the internals, which are not open-sourced to examine.

P.P.S. Also, my app is a single-process app, so it's unlikely that `Application.onStart()` will be called multiple times for me (unless I'm missing something here).

Comment: Hi were you able to do anything about this??

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about this question. Yes, I'm initializing it in the background and it works fine. I've disabled the content providers and load FirebaseApp on demand.

Comment: ok thanks Actine...

Answer (score 0):

From https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html

You can get your init info from google-services.json in your project or set a breakpoint in firebase init and see what's in the context.

Disable automatic init in your manifest...

```
<provider
    android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.firebaseinitprovider"
    tools:node="remove"
    />
```

If you don't have the "tools" namespace added to your manifest root tag, you'll have to add that as well:

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="your.package"
    >
```

Init explicitly in your code like this...
Could be called from a background thread here possibly...

```
FirebaseOptions.Builder builder = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setApplicationId("1:0123456789012:android:0123456789abcdef")
    .setApiKey("your_api_key")
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
    .setStorageBucket("your-app.appspot.com");
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this, builder.build());
```

Comment: When I initialise FirebaseApp on different thread.. since I am also using firebase performance library.. they create ANR as both tries to init same FirebaseApp on same lock.. any solution?